# Binding a value to an extension of a view in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I am trying to link an integer value in a list to an extension value "Index" of a StackLayout. Whatever I try to do, the value always ends up being 0, despite setting all data to "7"(random).

Code of the extension is as follows:

```
 public class NamedStackLayout : StackLayout
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }

        public static readonly BindableProperty IndexProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Index", typeof(int), typeof(NamedStackLayout), 1);

        public int IndexValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(IndexProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IndexProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

and override this method

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

after that call OnPropertyChanged in the setter of the IndexValue

Answer (score 0):

in your case,you should get the correct value with the `IndexValue` property.

e.g:

you binding the Index in your xaml :

```
  <local:NamedStackLayout x:Name="nameStackLayout" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Index="7">
     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></local:MyWeb>
  </local:NamedStackLayout>
```

then you could the value :

```
  var index = nameStackLayout.IndexValue;//here you could get the correct value 7.
```

or you could define the `Index` property in your custom stacklayout,keep the name as same as BindableProperty Name :

```
class NamedStackLayout:StackLayout
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IndexProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Index", typeof(int), typeof(NamedStackLayout), 1);

    public int Index
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(IndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IndexProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

then you could get the correct value with `Index` property.

e.g:

```
var index = nameStackLayout.Index;//here you could get the correct value 7.
```